# Is there a standard way to serialize JSON using JavaScript and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, google-api

I've been looking through Stackoverflow for answers and there seems to be more than one way of serializing (converting the JSON response back into HTML and/or other code so we may do something useful with it).

The way I am using is this..

```
$.getJSON(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?callback=?",
    {
        key: "unique key code", 
        country: "US", 
        q: "iphone", 
        alt: "json" 
    },
    function(data) 
{

$.each(data.items, function(i, item)
  {
  //Do something with each object
  }

}
```

So I'm using the $.getJSON method to retrieve the JSON response then looping through each object and doing something.

Is this way fine? Should I be using another function to retrieve the JSON response?

Regards,
LS

Comment: I don't think serialize is the right word. JSON is already serialized, it's just a String: it can be stored, it can be sent over the network.

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to describe the process of 'converting' it to a more presentable way for use on websites and apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you set `dataType` to `json` jquery parses json for you

```
$.ajax({
dataType:"json",
...
success:function(data){
$.each(data.items, function(i, item)
  {
  //Do something with each object
  }   
}

});
```

Comment: Pretty sure `$.getJSON()` does this internally anyway

Comment: @Phil yes but as i interpreted the question the OP wanted to know if he can use it without using `getJSON`

Comment: Can't see why you would want to do that. Each of the `$.get*()` and `$.post()` jQuery methods are simply wrappers around `$.ajax()`.

Comment: thats why i didn't wrote the explicit implementations the point was just to set `dataType` to `json`

Answer (score 2):

No, you are doing it perfectly fine. jQuery handles the conversion of "string" to json data and back.

There are native implementations of converting to and from JSON within browsers, however it is important to note that older browsers do **not** support this out of the box. You should [include the `json2.js` library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to ensure JSON support.

```
var dataJson={"something":"special"};
var jsonString=JSON.stringify(dataJson);
var dataJsonAgain=JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

jQuery has an additional hack in how it parses JSON if there is no native implementation, without using eval, since eval is evil! It looks somewhat like this;

```
(new Function("return "+dataJson))()
```

simplest way would be to stick to jQuery and its `parseJSON` function that does the polyfill for you.